# python -count elements pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a table with some info about districts. I have converted it into a pandas dataframe and my question is how can I count how many times SOUTHERN, BAYVIEW etc. appear in the table below? I want to add an extra column next to District with the total number of each district.

```
    District
0   SOUTHERN
1   BAYVIEW
2   CENTRAL
3   NORTH
```

Comment: What is your table? Is it df? Is it a pandas df a spark df?

Comment: Yes it is a pandas df. Sorry, my mistake

Comment: You should edit your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to use a `groupby` and a `size` method (you can also use some other aggregations such as count)

With this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'DISTRICT': ['SOUTHERN', 'SOUTHERN', 'BAYVIEW', 'BAYVIEW', 'BAYVIEW', 'CENTRAL', 'NORTH']})
```

Represented as below

```
     DISTRICT
0   SOUTHERN
1   SOUTHERN
2   BAYVIEW
3   BAYVIEW
4   BAYVIEW
5   CENTRAL
6   NORTH
```

You can use

```
df.groupby(['DISTRICT']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

You have this output

```
    DISTRICT    counts
0   BAYVIEW     3
1   CENTRAL     1
2   NORTH       1
3   SOUTHERN    2
```

Comment: Thank you but I have almost 100k observations regarding DISTRICT. I cannot just manually create the dataset to `df = pd.DataFrame`

Comment: I created the dataset for the example, just use the df you have :)

Comment: If you have a df with the district column then it is straight forward. If not this is not the same question

Comment: Yes it is very straight forward. I just did this: `df=df_can1` where `df_can1` is my dataset and after that I executed the `groupby` method. Thank you for your suggestions and help!

Comment: Do not hesitate to accept the answer :) (you can groupby on df_can1 aswell ! Youre welcome